# generating tuning parameter for Caret in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression, r-caret

I've been trying to use the caret package to do k-folds validation of a model. I've run lm() to some success, but when I try and do it with caret it fails. steps:

```
 train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)


 grid <- expand.grid(.fL=c(0), .usekernel=c(FALSE))


 model <- train(FantasyPTS ~ Shoots + Height + Weight + Birthyear + 
              age + Draft_Year + Overall_Draft_Num + Draft_Team + Draft_Age + 
             GAA + SVPCT + GSAA + QS + QS. + RBS + GPS, data=nhlgoalies, trControl=train_control, method="lm", tuneGrid=grid)
```

results in

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
  The tuning parameter grid should have columns intercept
```

my understanding was always that the model itself should generate the intercept. I know from reading the docs it needs the parameter intercept but I don't know how to generate it before the model itself is created?

Comment: try giving any random intercept value and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont give a link to a dataset, so I generate my one for example.

```
    ## Make data
ncol <- 3
Xs       <- matrix(rnorm(300*ncol), nrow = 300, ncol = ncol) %>% as.tibble()
Yvec     <- rnorm(300)
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)

    ## Fit lm model using train
fit  <- train(x= Xs, y = Yvec, method = "lm",trControl = train_control)
```

So you just don't need to specify  `tuneGrid` parameter and will be ok.

Comment: ok, this works well, and I understand why my adding a tuneGrid without the intercept param made the call fail, but I'm curious about the how/why around when people use tuneGrid and why that's something one would use? basically how does one decide to make it and use that or not and how does it change performance?